# How to send Array of values from android to php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, arrays

I want to send array of values from android to php to insert in to MySQL database. Here i am using Array list. Should i need to use JSONObject ? if yes how do send array values through JSON ? friends please help me

Here my code is

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> al = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

String id[]={"anu","bavi","citi" };

List<String> stfids=new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0;i<2;i++)

{
    stfids.add(id[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 

{
    al.add(new BasicNameValuePair("names["+i+"]",String.valueOf(stfids.get(i))));
}

String response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http:\\192.168.1.1\my-folder\myfile.php",al);

String result = response.toString();
```

**myfile.php**

```
$arr[] = $_REQUEST['names[]'];


for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)

 {

  echo $arr[$i] ;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSONObject which can put array as a json element.

for example:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("jsonArray",jsonArray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: then how do i pass this to php file ?? whether my php code is correct ?

Comment: Please do not ask to accept an answer. Certainly not if you push the OP only partly in a different direction. A different post for the php is non sense as it has to be coded together.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it like this:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();                  
try
{
    jObject.put("emailID", "data");
}catch(Exception ex){}
```

and send it as:

```
jObject.toString();
```